# SVN diff list commits

Tags: svn

What I'm looking for is:

```
svn diff a b
```

repeat for all files:

`svn blame b/file` (manually check rev on diffed lines)

```
svn log -rALL_REV_S_FOUND
```

E.g.

```
svn diff a b --list_commits
```

Wanted output e.g.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
rXXXXX | user | 2010-11-16 14:28:28 +0100 (Tue, 16 Nov 2010) | A line

Comment Q
------------------------------------------------------------------------
rXXXXZ | user | 2010-11-16 14:28:28 +0100 (Tue, 16 Nov 2010) | B line

Comment W
------------------------------------------------------------------------
rXXXXY | user | 2010-11-16 14:28:28 +0100 (Tue, 16 Nov 2010) | C line

Comment E
```

etc ....

To clarify even more (Git and SVN are fundamentally different so.):

```
git log master..branch
```

which can be read as

> Obtain a list of changes between
>   current branch, and master branch

Comment: It's not clear what you're after. Can you give an example of the output you expect?

Answer (score 0):

try svn2cl, if you give it to revisions on a branch (or trunk) it will generate the log you're looking for.

http://arthurdejong.org/svn2cl/

Comment: The problem is that this don't take in a count for already merged backport. E.g. version1 is branched from trunk, A ,B and C are added to trunk. B is now backported to version1, I now need something that says A and C are in version1.

Answer (score 0):

A command like `svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible ^/trunk ^/branches/foo` can give you the information you're looking for. As you can see in [the manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.mergeinfo.html), this prints a list of revision numbers. You can pass those to `svn log` with some scripting to get the kind of output you're looking for.

You might find that `svn mergeinfo` is less reliable than `git log`, though. In my experience with svn 1.6, it's fine if merges are happening only from `^/trunk` to `^/branches/foo`. If your merges are more complex (e.g. in both directions, or from a third branch to both `trunk` and `foo`, or to/from subdirectories) svn can become confused and will overstate the differences among branches (i.e. it will tell you that revisions have not been merged when in fact they have). Sometimes the confusion can be resolved by [hacks like this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.reintegratetwice).

Comment: "for X in $(svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible trunk branches/X ) ; do svn log -$X trunk; done" is good asuming you have done proper merges. But I'm in the siutaion with ~50% is not merges but commits. So this gives in my test case 2-3 times to many, suggestions. But i guess this is best we can expect from svn.